# Azure, App-service, create X509Certificate2 object from string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate, x509certificate2

Having an App-service in Azure, and working on the AzureServiceManagementAPI, I was downloading the file that contains the managememnt certificate for each subscription.

Any how using the certificate string from the file I'm trying to create a **X509Certificate2** object.

```
string cerStr = subscription.Attribute("ManagementCertificate").Value;
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cerStr), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
```

The constructor of X509Certificate2 throw an exception

> Access denied.
>
> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32
>   hr) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet,
>   SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx) at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[]
>   rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)

Comment: Have you tried X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has answered this questions, I will try and have go at it. Please correct me if I am wrong, but the problem I think is the following line of code:

```
new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cerStr), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
```

This line of code will try to add a new certificate to the certificate store of the virtual machine. All certificates used by the runtime, needs to be hosted in a store somewhere. This is not a good idea because the certificate store of the virtual machine hosting the app service is nothing that you should be storing anything in, it's part of the infrastructure which is not of your concern when you are working with app services.

What you need to do is to upload the certificate through the azure portal instead (if they are not already there). I ended up reusing a SSL certificate already in place for this purpose. When this is done, you can retreive that certificate in code. You will need to add a new App Setting under "Application Settings" key in the Azure portal for your app service, named  WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES. The value should be the thumbprint of the certificate.

To retrieve the cert, you should do something like this:

```
public async Task<X509Certificate2> GetCertificate(string certificateThumbprint)
{
    var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var cert = store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Thumbprint == certificateThumbprint);
    store.Close();
    return cert;
}
```

You might be able to get thumbprint of the cert by navigating your subscription using the azure resource explorer https://resources.azure.com/

Comment: From my experience, certificates will be installed in the CurrentUser.

Comment: Is there not anyway around this? Some of us load certificates from external services.

Answer (score 0):

As Fredrik mentioned the issue is due to the code

```
X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(cerStr), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)
```

In the Azure WebApp, if we try to use the certificate, we need to upload the certificate from the Azure portal. Add the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with thumbprint value in the Azure WebApp application. More detail info please refer to [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).

Web application to access the certificate, snippet code from the blog

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
      certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                                 X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                                 // Replace below with your cert's thumbprint
                                 “E661583E8FABEF4C0BEF694CBC41C28FB81CD870”,
                                 false);
      // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
      if (certCollection.Count > 0)
      {
        X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
        // Use certificate
        Console.WriteLine(cert.FriendlyName);
      }
      certStore.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Is there not anyway around this? Some of us load certificates from external services.